# Why Livepatch is not available for ARM based CPU?

Tags: raspberrypi, arm, canonical-livepatch, 22.04

I recently discovered Canonical Livepatch service, I want to install it on my Raspberry Pi, but it said `Livepatch is not available for platform arm64. Supported platforms are: amd64, x86_64.`

Livepatch official website said: Livapatch is only available in x86 or amd64 CPU, why it is not available for arm-based CPU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be pure guessing from my side, since it's Canonical who has taken the decision to offer Livepatch only for the `amd64` architecture.

But I guess that it's simply a business decision based on the fact that demand for livepatching on ARM architecture isn't high enough to throw in the resources to do it.

As far as I understand, kernel livepatching is rather complicated to do, and it must be done for each kernel architecture separately.

However, to get a full answer, you probably have to ask some technical support at Canonical.

Comment: I would guess that this might change in future, since the rise of new ARM server technologies. But this might take some time.

Comment: I believe you're right - it would be the logical next step. But only Canonical knows if and when this change will be implemented.

Comment: I agree your answer, thanks for replying!